# Comments to Projects and Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just new to rails and I'm trying to put together a comment feature on my app. However I'm getting the now annoying

```
Couldn't find Project without an ID
```

Routes.rb

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :comments
  end
```

User model.

```
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments
```

Project model.

```
  belong_to :user
  has_many :comments , dependent: :destroy
```

Comments model.

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
```

Comments controller.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

def create
   @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
   @comment = @project.comments.build(comment_params)
   @comment.user_id = current_user.id
       if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
      redirect_to @project
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Sorry! your comment was not created"
    end
  end


 def destroy
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
end

end
```

Result

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+/UjIRKAjE+DAATW6eV48xjX+6WW6a/y7Q8DS+nLeCnM8nzwpdzW1FuGXtXVpCGFS0vPivvMi7jvus9IQcjLjA==", "comment"=>{"body"=>""}, "commit"=>"Comment"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Project without an ID):
```

---- Update 1 -------

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Write here" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As you see in the log params[:project_id] was not sent (no project_id in Parameters hash)

Comment: You don't have `:project_id` in your params

Comment: can you please post `form` which is used to create the comment

Comment: is it neccesary to include those in the comments_params? and why?

Comment: @Eltorero1992: "and why?" - huh? Because your code expects it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev hahaha thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's written on your **form_url**. But, definitely it is missing the `project_id`. So, I suggest you to use the following code:

```
<%= form_for [@project, @comment] do |f| %>
```

It'll create a POST request in `root/projects/2/comments`

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll give it a go later on and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your posts below is the right solution

```
<%= form_for ([@project , @comment]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Params

```
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body,:project_id,:user_id)
end
```